# iOS Swift Canvas Drawing and frame function

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ios13

I am fairly new to iOS Development and I have a question, where the internet couldn't help me.
At first, I want to have a canvas, where I can draw rects, circles, lines, etc. I already tried the 'workaround' with the image view, but I don't think, that this is a clean solution and it's really not that efficient. 
Secondly, is there any function, which gets called every frame? Currently I have a timer which calls a function every 1/60 second, but I've read, that this also isn't very efficient.

Thanks for any response in advance!

Comment: [`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink), maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a canvas with animation support on iOS?
1.need a canvas? a UIView and its sub class is simply a canvas,you can draw shapes in draw method

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

}
```

2.you want to implement fancy animation on canvas? search CALayer Animation on google and you will get tons of resources teaching you how.Not like other canvas animation,you do not have to use a timer to draw frame animation on iOS.